# Display last n characters of a string

Tags: c++

I need help with an assignment regarding c-strings and functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//other functions
char display_last_nchar(char sent[], int n); // function i'm having trouble with
void main()
{
char sentence[31];
int selection, n;

do {
    cout << "Please enter a string: " << endl;
    cin.getline(sentence, 31, '\n'); //also, for me here i have to hit enter twice. How can I fix that?
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Please make a selection: " << endl;
    //other options
    cout << "4. Display the last n character of the string " << endl;
    cout << "7. Exit" << endl;
    cin >> selection;
    cin.ignore();

    switch (selection)
    {
    case 4:
        cout << "How many characters from the end of the string "
            << "do you want to display? : " << endl;
        cin >> n;
        cin.ignore();
        if (n >= 30)
        {
            cout << "Error: too many characters" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        display_last(sentence, n);
        cout << sentence << endl;
        break;
    case 7:
        break;
    }
} 
    while (choice != 7);

//other functions
char display_last_nchar(char sent[], int n)
{
    for (int i = n; n > 30; i++)
    {
    sent[i]; //I know this is wrong but this is a guess that i took
    }
return sent[n];
}
```

I know that how to display the first n characters of a string. For that function, if the user entered a string called "My hamster has a new toy" and they wanted to display the first 8 characters, it would set ever character after the 8th one to null, and thus only display "My hams."

What I tried to do, for the display_last_nchar was set, every character before the user inputted number to 0, but all that did was null the whole string.

Could someone please explain to me, the steps I would need to take in order to create a function that would display the last n characters of the string. I've tried looking online and in my book but it didn't really help me.

Comment: Do you want to only display or display and modify the original?

Comment: I only want to display the characters after the user inputted number. So if the string was "Hello there" and the user wanted to display the last 3 characters of the string, only "ere" would be displayed in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to a `char` is often considered to be a C-string. For example, the operator for formatted output (`operator<<()` does so). C strings follow a specific convention: they are terminated by the first null character encountered. When an array is used in a context where a pointer to an object is expected, they "decay" into a corresponding object.

To print the first `n` characters of a `char` array `sentence` you just need to set `sentence[n]` to null before using it with the output operator. You could use `std::ostream`'s unformatted output function `write()`, instead, to avoid modifying the string (e.g., string literals cannot be modified):

```
std::cout.write(sentence, n);
```

Printing an object is normally considered a non-modifying operation, i.e., I'd use the unformatted output to print the first `n` character or something which writes individual character like using

```
std::copy(sentence, sentence + n, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

To print the last `n` character you need to find the length of the string `s`, determine if `s` is bigger than `n`, and, if so, simply start printing at `sentence + (n - s)`. You could use either the formatted or unformatted approach to writing the last `n` characters. For symmetry I'd use the same approach for writing the first `n` character but starting elsewhere.

BTW, you should *always* determine if your input was successful after reading, e.g.:

```
if (std::cin >> n) {
    // use n
}
else {
    // report a read failure and potentially try to recover
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use C++ string STL. The [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method will be useful here. For example, to output last `n` characters of a string

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    int n;
    getline(cin, s);
    cin >> n;
    if (n < s.length())
        cout << s.substr(s.length() - n) << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not enough characters\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
My hamster has a new toy
5
```

**Output**

```
w toy
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straightforward question. You have a starting point and you need to display it till the end of the string.
You can iterate over the characters of the string starting from position n, up until you read a null (Which is used to indicate the termination of a string of characters).

```
char *display_last_nchar(char sent[], int n)
{
  char buff[100];
  int i = strlen(sent) - n; char ch;
  while((ch = sent[i])!='\0')
  {
    strcat(buff, ch);
  }
  strcat(buff, '\0');
  return buff;
}
```

Character arrays (or arrays of any type) are passed around as pointers, so the return type you'd use is a char pointer and not just char.
This function will return the pointer to the buffer that stores the last n characters. Remember, strlen and strcat are functions in the string.h library.